# Why is the greedy heuristic admissible and consistent for food at corners problem, but not for food anywhere problem?

Tags: python, search, heuristics, path-finding, goal-based-agents

UCBerkley has a great Intro to AI course (CS188) where you can practice coding up search algorithms. One of the exercises ([question 6](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ecs188/sp22/project1/#question-1-3-points-finding-a-fixed-food-dot-using-depth-first-search)), asks to generate a heuristic that will have Pacman find all 4 corners of the grid.

My implementation used a *greedy* approach that found the closest corner by Manhattan distance, moved Pacman to that corner, and then repeated the process. This is a relaxation of the original problem by removing all the walls. Here is my code below:

```
def cornersHeuristic(state: Any, problem: CornersProblem):

    corners = list(problem.corners) # These are the corner coordinates
    
    position, corners_status = state
    
    bools = [x==0 for x in corners_status]
    unexplored_corners = []
    
    for index, bool_val in enumerate((bools)):
        if bool_val == True:
            unexplored_corners.append(corners[index])
    
    current_sum = 0    
    while unexplored_corners != []:
        
        dists_temp = []
    
        for corner in unexplored_corners:
        
            d = util.manhattanDistance(position, corner)
            dists_temp.append(d)
        
        min_dist = min(dists_temp)
        current_sum = current_sum + min_dist
        position = unexplored_corners.pop(dists_temp.index(min_dist))

    return current_sum
```

This implementation ended up working correctly and the autograder recognized it as consistent.
However, upon closer inspection, I think the autograder made a mistake. Here is an example of where my greedy heuristic would find a path longer than the theoretical shortest path available for Pacman:

The blue line is the path my heuristic would take and the green line is the correct shortest path.

[image]

What am I missing here? Why is this heuristic consistent? **And why is this greedy heuristic consistent for the corners problem, but not for the "food anywhere" problem?** Any visualization showing a simple scenario where it would fail for the "food anywhere" problem would be greatly appreciated since Im a visual learner.

Comment: Someone asked a very similar question on Stackoverflow just the other day: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73680177

Comment: I disagree. My question is asking why this greedy heuristic is consistent and I provided a figure showing how its not a lower bound on the closest manhattan distance